# HTTP 401 Error on all outbound HTTP connections

Tags: java, web-services, rest, httpurlconnection

We have an older application that connects to a RESTful service and a JAX-WS service.  Both services utilize basic http authentication (user/password).  When we start the application, it works properly.  After a number of weeks/months, the application starts to receive the 401 errors from both service calls.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://myserver.com/rest/endpoint
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1313)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
```

AND

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Access Denied
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:196)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:168)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:83)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:105)
```

If we stop the application, and restart it, the application starts to work again.  The 401 errors go away without any modification to the services themselves.

Here is the code we used for the RESTful service.

```
private String callService (String requestXml)  {
            String response = "";
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            URL url = null;
            DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            String token = null;

            try {

                    url = new URL(SERVICE_URL);
                    token = Base64Encoder.encode (USER_ID +":"+PASSWD);  //username and password
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();                   
                    connection.setReadTimeout(TIME_OUT_SECONDS);
                   connection.setUseCaches (false);      
                   connection.setDoInput(true);      
                   connection.setDoOutput(true);
                   connection.setRequestMethod(HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD_GET);
                   connection.setRequestProperty(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_XML);
                   connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + token);

                   outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                   outputStream.writeBytes(requestXml);
                   outputStream.flush();
                   outputStream.close();

                   //Now Retrieve the Response

                   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
```

I am trying to figure out why this happens over time, any ideas?

Comment: Once you get `401`, you start getting it for all the requests or only some requests?

Comment: As far as we can tell, once it starts, all subsequent calls fails with the 401.

Comment: Looks like your `USER_ID` and `PASSWD` are probably static variables?  From the code snippet you provided, the most likely thing I see is that the `USER_ID` and/or `PASSWD` variables had their values modified.

Have you attached a debugger to the running application that is throwing the 401's to check these variables?

If you can't do that, can you debug the HTTP server you're targeting, attach to that and decode the base64 auth header to verify its contents

Comment: The user ID and password variables for both methods (jax-ws and rest) are independent. In addition, they are static finals, and should not be able to be modified.

Comment: Well. I think you hit the nail on the head. I was told it was static final, but I looked for myself. It is not. I think you are right and the variable is changing and now the value is incorrect.